# Exporting a Windows Forms control created from Visual Studio 2010 Designer

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

How can I export a control that was created in Visual Studio Designer for a Windows Forms Project.  The purpose is to allow Controls to be built generically, packaged and available as references for other projects.

Comment: Declare the class public.  That's all.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2010 > New Class Library > call it `CtrlLibrary` > Add a User Control called SuperButton with a button.

Compile the Class Library into a DLL.

Either:
a) File > Close Solution > New Winform Project > Reference the DLL
Or b) File > Add New Winform Project to the solution and reference the Class Library project.

In both scenarios you will open a Window Form, open the ToolBox and see the SuperButton User Control that you drag onto the Form.